# Python function is returning an empty list

Tags: python, debugging, methods, nonetype

So, I have a function that is supposed to accept a list of class instances, modify the list of class instances, and then return the modified class instances. However, the list, is being returned empty, even though I have values in the list before I return the list. The code is posted below:

```
def calculate(self,solution_list):
    """
    Calculates the ranked fitness for the solution list.
    Returns the solution list with evaluated fitnesses.


    """

    Block_of_unimportant_code

    print("Ranked fitness solution")
    print(solution_list)
    return solution_list


print("Before I do fitness calculation")'''
print(solution_list)
solution_list = self.fitness.calculate(solution_list)
print("AFter fitness is calculated")
print(solution_list)
```

When I execute the code, this is what is given in the print statements:

Before I do fitness calculation

[class_instance0x2aab3fdc4ed0, class_instance0x2aab3fdc0350, class_instance0x2aab3fdc7ed0, class_instance0x2aab3fdb4e10, class_instance0x2aab3fdcdc10, class_instance0x2aab3fdc4190, class_instance0x2aab3fdc9c90, class_instance0x2aab3fdd1b10, class_instance0x2aab3fdd87d0, class_instance0x2aab3fdd4a10, class_instance0x2aab3fdd6890, class_instance0x2aab3fdda710, class_instance0x2aaab4beb410, class_instance0x2aab3fddc650, class_instance0x2aab3fddf4d0, class_instance0x2aab3fdde590]

Ranked fitness solution

[class_instance0x2aab3fdc4ed0, class_instance0x2aab3fdc0350, class_instance0x2aab3fdc7ed0, class_instance0x2aab3fdb4e10, class_instance0x2aab3fdcdc10, class_instance0x2aab3fdc4190, class_instance0x2aab3fdc9c90, class_instance0x2aab3fdd1b10, class_instance0x2aab3fdd87d0, class_instance0x2aab3fdd4a10, class_instance0x2aab3fdd6890, class_instance0x2aab3fdda710, class_instance0x2aaab4beb410, class_instance0x2aab3fddc650, class_instance0x2aab3fddf4d0, class_instance0x2aab3fdde590]

AFter fitness is calculated

None

So obviously the list of instances has values when it is called, has values right before it is returned, and loses them as soon as they are returned, and I genuinely don't understand what the cause of this is.

Any feedback or advice for fixing the problem would be genuinely appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very specific and has entirely too many conditionals to read. You should reformat your question to be focus on the exact minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue, not a wall of text. It's difficult for anyone to see what you're trying to do, for example, why is your third loop over solution_list when your second look is doing mutational sort?

Comment: That function is the method of a class?

Comment: @AMC yes. It is a method within an initialized class.

Comment: @W4t3randWind I removed the unnecessary blocks of code. Basically, when I pass the list into the method, it has values. When I check the list in the function it has values. When I return the list it is suddenly an empty list. Somehow the variable solution_list is being reassigned sometime between the print statement within the method, and the return.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full code.
Also, are you sure you meant to write self.fitness.calculate(solution_list)?

Comment: I got a comment earlier that it was too confusing of a post with the full code posted. But the part of code that I removed shouldn't really impact things, because the code works up to that point. And yes, it should be self.fitness.calculate(solution_list). The class fitness is initiated as an object within another larger class.

Comment: Hm... why do you have ''' in line  print("Before I do fitness calculation")'''

Comment: It was part of my personal debugging. I kept it here however to show that the variable has values when it is passed into the method. Then the second in-line print shows that the list has values in it right before the return statement, and the third one shows that there aren't any values after the function.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the posted code. I think I would need to see the full code, including the parts that were excluded.